# ReactJS Props Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, react-props

I am learning how to use props. After taking research in either my mother language or english, I couldn't end up with a proper answer for my issue.
Please tell me why this threw errors. This is the App.js file (default)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Product7 from './componentep7/Product7';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <a className="navbar-brand" >Title</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div className="container">
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">


  
    <Product7 name="valiant"/>

    

  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

and this is the component file (Product7.js)
everything is fine except it returned an error at {this.props.name}

```
import React from 'react';


function Product7() {
  return (
    <div>
    <div className="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
      <a className="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://yuzu-emu.org/images/game/boxart/hollow-knight.png" alt="5tr"/>
      
      </a>
      <div className="caption">

<h4>{this.props.name}</h4>

     
      <a className="btn btn-primary">Click to enter</a>

      </div>
      
          </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Product7;
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: you can't use this in functional component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Props are passed as an argument to function components. You can’t reference `this.props`. Access it from the `props` argument:

```
function Product7 (props) {
  return (
    <h4>{props.name}</h4>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

don't use `this` in functional components,  `<h4>{props.name}</h4>`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the props in the component, you must define it as a parameter:

```
function Product7(props) {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant use this in functional component.
Please go through this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    
    function Product7({name}) {
      return (
        <div>
        <div className="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
          <a className="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://yuzu-emu.org/images/game/boxart/hollow-knight.png" alt="5tr"/>
          
          </a>
          <div className="caption">
    
    <h4>{name}</h4>
    
         
          <a className="btn btn-primary">Click to enter</a>
    
          </div>
          
              </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Product7;


  [1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass props as an argument in your component.

```
function Product7(props){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing props in functional components you have to pass `props` as an argument for the function.

Another thing is, no need to use `this` keyword in functional components.

```
function Product7 (props) {
return (
  .
  .
  .
 <h4>{props.name}</h4>
   )
}
```

Note: It is a good habit to practice ECMA Script 6 arrow functions when using functional components, as below.

```
const Product7 = (props) => {
return (
  .
  .
  .
 <h4>{props.name}</h4>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot using `props` within the paranthesis.

```
function Product7 (props) {
...
...
}
```

Oh, and make sure not to use `this.props` as you are using a function based component (only class based components need using `this.props`)

Answer (score 0):

catch the data by adding props in your function and call it without using **this** because you are using functional component. i suggest to learn the class component first before jumping functional component